# CheckBox being checked but not doing function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I am currently using php loops to spawn in panels from a database.
On each of these panels there is a checkbox. When checked it checks all the checkboxes under it in the collapsible panels.

When the check boxes in the panels get checked by the checkbox in the panel header it is meant to run a function which updates my database saying that box is checked. The function works when you down the collapsible panels a check the box manually. But when you check the box from a higher level and check all the boxes bellow it, it doesnt run the onchange function i have put in.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Kristian

PHP:

```
foreach ($results3 as $table3) {
        $output_string .= "<div class=\"panel-inner\">\n";
        $output_string .= "<div class=\"row\">\n";
        $output_string .= "<div class=\"col-sm12\">\n";
        $output_string .= "<div class=\"panel-body\">\n";
        $output_string .= "<h4 class=\"panel-title\">\n";
        $output_string .= "<a>$table3[Call_Flow]</a>\n";
        $output_string .= "<input class=\"mycheckbox\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$table3[Test_ID]\" onchange=\"adds(tccb$j)\" id=\"tccb$j\"/>\n";
        $output_string .= "</h4>\n";
            $output_string .= "</div>\n";
        $output_string .= "<div id=\"collapseflow$j\" class=\"panel-body collapse\">\n";
```

HTML:

```
<div id="check">

    </div>

    <script>
    function adds(id) {

    var value = $(id).val()

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "selection_update.php",
            data: {"value": value},
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
                success:function(responce){
                $("#check").html(responce);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Edit:

This is the code i am using to check all my child checkboxs.

```
$output_string .= "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\">\n";
$output_string .= "function checkCheckboxes( id, pID ){\n";
$output_string .= "$('#'+pID).find(':checkbox').each(function(){\n";
$output_string .= "jQuery(this).prop('checked', $('#' + id).is(':checked'));\n";
$output_string .= "});\n";     
$output_string .= "}\n";
$output_string .= "</script>\n";
```

Comment: The PHP code is useless. Show the HTML it outputs as that is what we need to see.

Comment: where are you executing adds(...)?

Comment: did you missed the `onchange` handler in checkbox @edgaromar90 ?

Comment: totally missed it! my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `onchange` only reacts to user clicks, not a simply value change. To get around this you need to trigger the `onchange` function manually.

So in your oarent's onchange function, make sure you select the relevant children and call `.onchange()` on them.

Here is an example where one checkbox changes another, without the `.onchange()` call:

https://jsfiddle.net/c1zwek1u/

And here it is with:

https://jsfiddle.net/c1zwek1u/1/

Notice that it should alert you when the child's value changes.

For multiple children you simply need to iterate over the group and call it on each child individually like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/c1zwek1u/3/

In Jquery, you can trigger the change like so `$(selector).trigger('change');`

Comment: okay cool, this is along the right line :) what happens when you have multiple children? i am currently group checking my checkboxs by what div they are in

Comment: i have edited my post to show how i am currently checking and unchecking with my parent check box.

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to handle multiple children using a loop.

Comment: Since you're using JQuery (though you don't need to) I added a line on how to trigger the change using JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the adds(param) as a string. And because you are using it to get the DOM element you need to add the hashtag to

**Change this line:**

```
$output_string .= "<input class=\"mycheckbox\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$table3[Test_ID]\" onchange=\"adds(tccb$j)\" id=\"tccb$j\"/>\n";
```

**Into this line:**

```
$output_string .= "<input class=\"mycheckbox\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$table3[Test_ID]\" onchange=\"adds('#tccb$j')\" id=\"tccb$j\"/>\n";
```